# how to update angular storybook for correct source code example?

Tags: angular, storybook, angular-storybook

i have component witch is rendered like this

```
     <app-content-tabs>

        <app-tab tabTitle="Request info">tab 1 content</app-tab>

        <app-tab tabTitle="Subject details">tab 2 content</app-tab>

     </app-content-tabs>
```

i also have story for the component:

```
import {ContentTabsComponent} from "../../../../app/components/ui/content-tabs/content-tabs.component";

import {ContentTabsModule} from "../../../../app/components/ui/content-tabs/content-tabs.module";

import {Meta, Story} from "@storybook/angular/types-6-0";

import {moduleMetadata} from "@storybook/angular";



export default  {

  component: ContentTabsComponent,

  decorators: [

    moduleMetadata({

      declarations: [ ],

      imports: [ContentTabsModule ],

      providers: []

    })],

  title: 'Components/ui/content-tabs',

} as Meta



const Template: Story<ContentTabsComponent> = (args: ContentTabsComponent) => ({

  props: args,

  template: `

  <div style="width: 256px;height: 698px">

  <app-content-tabs>

    <app-tab tabTitle="Request info">tab 1 content</app-tab>

    <app-tab tabTitle="Subject details">tab 2 content</app-tab>

   </app-content-tabs>

</div>

  `

});





export const TabsExample = Template.bind({});
```

the problem is in the storybook web app when i go into the docs of the component and copy the source code its generates only this:

```
<app-content-tabs></app-content-tabs>
```

how can i fix the source code to show the full example with the code projected into the ng-content?

i tried to find in the storybook docs but no luck

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the html template into the individual story itself.

Change the `const Template` line as follows:

```
const Template: Story<ContentTabsComponent> = (args: ContentTabsComponent) => ({
  props: args
});
```

Then put the html template into the example:

```
export const TabsExample: Story = (args: ContentTabsComponent) => ({
  props: args,
  template: `
    <div style="width: 256px;height: 698px">
      <app-content-tabs>
        <app-tab tabTitle="Request info">tab 1 content</app-tab>
        <app-tab tabTitle="Subject details">tab 2 content</app-tab>
      </app-content-tabs>
    </div>
  `
});
```

After that you can specify the args for the `app-content-tabs` if you need to:

```
TabsExample.args = {
  foo: 'bar'
}
```

Copy code in storybook *should* give you the whole template then.